# How to restart try loop if exception occurs

Tags: python, selenium, loops, try-catch

I am writing a webscraper that uses data from a already existing spreadsheet to pull data from a website. It uses codes (that reference products) from a certain column to search the site. However, when searching for one product, multiple are displayed with only one being a correct match. I have created a system that can search for the correct code and select the product via `find_element_by_xpath`, but it does not account for multiple pages. My goal is to (upon the code not being found) move to the next page and search for the same code without moving to the next excel row, stopping when the final page is reached. I have already found a snippet of code that should work on moving to the next page:

```
try:
    _driver.find_element_by_class_name("next").click()
    print("Navigating to Next Page")
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("Final Page")
    break
```

However, I am unsure where/how I would implement this without either breaking the code, or moving down by a row.
Here is a snippet of how my code works so far (obviously simplified)

```
for i in data.index: #(_data is spreadsheet column)
    try:
        # locate product code
        # copy product link
        # navigate to link

        try:
        # wait for site to load 

        # Copy data to Spreadsheet 

        except TimeoutException:
        # Skip if site takes too long

     except Exception as e:
     # Catch any possible exceptions and continues loop (normally when product cannot be found)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, whether it be how to implement the code snippet above, or a better way to go about moving from page to page. IF needed I can supply a link to the website or snippets of my code in further detail :)

Comment: Put your try/except call inside a function and then call that function when needed.

Comment: You could use a boolean variable and change that boolean variable to true when the try block succeeds. Then put all the try and except in a while loop checking if this boolean variable is still false, so it will execute the try and catch until the try block succeeds.

Comment: @Wahalez Which try block? and then when u say all the try and accept in a while loop, i assume you mean the next page snippet.

Comment: @Wahalez and where exactly would the try/except while loop be located? Because I need it to run without increasing i in _data.index

Comment: @DanCurry The Try/Except next page function? and that could work, ill give it a shot

Comment: @RohaanPatel-Kumar My answer is a general answer, you need to implement it in your code as you design it. It is an idea of how you can execute the try-except block over and over again until it succeeds. Hope it helps

Comment: Also, I think recursion will be a much better approach to your needs.

Comment: @Wahalez I tried running the function within except Exception as e, but that creates the issue that the code runs it, but then restarts 'for i in data.index', meaning it moves down by one cell which is the issue i was running into earlier. I'm just clueless as to where to run this code snippet. If I shared a full copy/paste of my code, would you be able to show me where i would insert the code/function

Comment: @Wahalez I just did some quick research on recursion and it seems like its exactly what i need, but i have absolutely no clue how to use it. I think for now using try should get the job done, i just am not sure when to insert the try/except snippet of code

Comment: @RohaanPatel-Kumar In the for loop that goes over each cell, call a [recursion](https://realpython.com/python-recursion/) function that will travel to the next page until it is the final page and process what you need if you found it ( the product you're looking for ).

Answer (score 1):

How I went about it (Storing the page mover and code checker as functions and using them to call each other):

```
def page_mover():
    try:
        # Click Next page
        page_link()
    except Exception:
        print("Last page reached")

def page_link():
    try:
        # Wait for page to load
        # Get link using product code
        # Go to link
    except Exception:
        page_mover()
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python program terminates as soon as it encounters an error. In Python, an error can be a syntax error or an exception. The [try-except](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/) code lets you test code and catch the exception that might occur without terminating the program.

To your question, you might want to use [recursion functions](https://realpython.com/python-recursion/) in order to travel through the pages.

You could try something like this :

```
def rec(site, product):
    if(final-page)
        return exception_not_found

    try:
        # locate product code

        try:
        # wait for site to load 
        # Copy data to Spreadsheet 
        if(found_product)
            return #found, break

        except TimeoutException:
        return # Skip if site takes too long
    except Exception as e:
        return # Skip if fails ? 

    if(we_did_not_find_product)
        # copy product link
        # navigate to link
        #navigate to next site
        rec(next_site, product)


for i in data.index: #(_data is spreadsheet column)
    rec(init_side, i)
```

Meaning for each row in the spreadsheet, we go the the initial page, look for the product, if we did not find it, moving to next page until either we found the product or we reached the last page. Going to next row in cases : if exception occures, found the product, reached next page.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all the advice, I ended up essentially storing the code checker and the page clicker as 2 separate functions, and using them to call each other. It seems to work as it ran through all the data I have been given with no errors